# filter: Trying to find 2 specific rows that failed to parse

Tags: r, datetime, filter

I am trying to clean my data in R. I'm trying to check if all rows in a column are consistent because of this warning :

> X202204$started_at <- ymd_hms(X202204$started_at)
> Warning message:
> 2 failed to parse.

So I checked the data types of this column

```
class(X202204$started_at)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

POSIXt isn't even a recognized class of data, which is weird. I thought the only 2 types were POSIXct and POSIXlt?

I'm trying to find these 2 rows to see why they weren't converted to date-time. I thought I could filter the data by rows in the column "started_at" that don't conform to the date time.

```
X202204 <- X202204 %>% 
    select_if(is.POSIXt)
```

There's no output. I'm not sure what to do. I feel like working with SQL would be easier but I'm not allowed to upload anything over 100MB and half my dataframes are over 100MB, so I'm using R for now.

Comment: Just look for which ones returned `NA` after running `ymd_hms(X202204$started_at)`

Comment: POSIXt is an implicit superclass. Both POSIXct and POSIXlt are members  You seems to be using a package that is not in base. Perhaps 'lubridate'? Your failed to parse items are probably now NA's.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the relevant column, perform the change, and then filter to the relevant rows this way:

```
library(tidyverse)

X202204 |>
  select(started_at) |>
  mutate(new = ymd_hms(started_at)) |>
  filter(is.na(new))
```